# How can I prove this relation between gcd(a,b)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

I am stuck on starting this proof that involves gcd.

Define $g_n=2^{2^n}+1$ and that $g_0g_1g_2...g_{n-1}=g_n-2$. Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are unequal positive integers. Prove that $gcd(g_a,g_b)=1$.

Do I need to use Euclid's algorithm? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting to see this is a prime number generator - g0=3, g1=5, g2=17, g3=257 etc. Some other formula's for prime http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Euclid's algorithm. Without loss of generality you can assume $a < b$ and write the equation $g_0 g_1 \cdots g_{b-1} = g_b - 2$ as 
$$c g_a - g_b = -2$$ where $c = \prod_{i = 0, i \neq a}^{b-1} g_i$.
Now use this equation to get some restriction on the possible common divisors of $g_a$ and $g_b$. Because $g_a$ and $g_b$ are odd numbers, you will be able to conclude $\gcd(g_a,g_b) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \gcd(g_a,g_b) \overset{a\,<\,b}= \gcd(\color{#c00}{g_a},\, 2+g_0\!\cdots \color{#c00}{g_a}\!\cdots g_{b-1}) = \gcd(g_a,\ \ldots)\,$ by $\,\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x,\, y\ {\rm mod}\ x)$